# How can I change <li> class on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Could someone tell me how can I set a class on nav buttons on scroll like that [Website(select AJAX PORTFOLIO )](http://tommusdemos.wpengine.com/demo-selector/?theme=Lumos)

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried !

Comment: I have triend AJAX PORTFOLIO template. It is the first template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){ 
    $('ul li').removeClass("active");
    $('ul li').addClass("deactive");
 });
   });
</script>
<style>
.active{
    color:red;
}
.deactive{
color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="height:9500px;">
<ul>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
<li class="active">a</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use an event listener to run code when the window is scrolled.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){ 
     //your code here
     $("li").removeClass("classToRemove", function(){
        $("li").addClass("classToAdd");
     });
 });
```

Comment: I would use callbacks when removing/adding the class.

Comment: I don't know how can I change button active class on scroll like that website [ AJAX PORTFOLIO ](http://tommusdemos.wpengine.com/demo-selector/?theme=Lumos)

Comment: You can use the same approach with the scroll listener. Just replace the inner code to change the button status.

`$("button").prop("disabled", true);`

Change to false to make it enabled.